# Opennssl command to use s_server argument along with Cipher

Tags: openssl

Can any one help me out how to use the cipher argument in openssl command along with the s_server argument..

@present my command is this..

openssl s_server -accept 11651 -cert MVNR1.crt -key MVNR1.key -CAfile SS8CA1.crt -tlsextdebug  -msg -state -debug

But I want to allow for particular cipher say TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

I have googled and tried several commands.

openssl ciphers -v 'SSLV3:RSA:+AES256:+SHA'

openssl ciphers -v 'RSA:+DHE:+AES256:+SHA'

openssl ciphers -v 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA'

these commands shows some outputs regarding to cipher. But the real problem starts here. I want to use this Cipher along with the s_server argument

openssl ciphers -v 'TLS:RSA:+AES256:+CBC:+SHA' s_server -accept 11651 -cert MVNR1.crt -key MVNR1.key -CAfile SS8CA1.crt -tlsextdebug  -msg -state -debug

I tried this command. It is not working. Can anyone tell me how to use this pls..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `s_server` as the standard command, and then use the `-ciphers` options from `s_server` options, which uses the standard cipherlist.

Something like:

```
 openssl s_server -accept 11651 -cert certificate.crt -key key.key -CAfile ca.crt -tlsextdebug -cipher 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA'-msg -state -debug
```

Of course, remove the debug options, if you were just using them for debugging this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply. Actually I have sorted out the problem without specifying the cipher. But this would be very much useful for me. Thank you once again